# Cannot upload files in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am using ASP .NET with Razor and trying to upload file. But it is not upload neither it shows any errors.

This is my form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Account/ApplyJobTo">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="4dcsxIcQdtZTFIm80O-qZ4COPjvj_gm0EPCxUxVgVi8nKtIIl4rPHbw9IyNsHDsU-KUZCnBh6WrDyNiz-LQfMf-SxxOlaZw3Y3Ai4EZb11z44-J0c7XjAyqBSqm82OLJ0" />

<label for="job">Jobs</label>
<select name="job" id="job" required>
    <option disabled selected>Select Job</option>
<option value='1'>Manager</option><option value='2'>Directory</option>    </select>
<label for="cv">Upload CV (only PDF)</label>
<input type="file" required id="cv" name="File1" />
       <input type="submit" value="Apply" name="apply" />

</form>
```

And this is my code in ApplyJobTo

```
@{ 
var File1 = Request.Files;
foreach (string file in File1)
{
    var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
    if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        if (fileContent.ContentType == "pdf")
        {
            var stream = fileContent.InputStream;
            // and optionally write the file to disk
            var fileName = (int)Session["user_id"] + "-" + fileContent.FileName;
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Assets/CV/"), fileName.ToString());
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                var _db = Database.Open("mcj");
                string job_id = Request.Form["job"];
                int user_id = (int)Session["user_id"];
                _db.Execute("INSERT INTO job_requests (job_id, user_id, cv) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", job_id, user_id, fileName);

                Response.Write("Job Applied");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Only PDFs are allowed");
    }
}
}
```

Also, I have a query written when the file is uploaded, and also it doesn't add in database. I am not getting any errors, just a blank page. Cannot understand what is wrong.

Comment: What does the HTTP look like?

Comment: Oh wait, what, what, wheres your controller? Hmm, do you understand how MVC works? This code suggests not?

Comment: Sorry, auto-tag

Comment: Why have you removed the MVC tag? Razor cannot work without MVC. Seriously, this may work (somehow) but you are doing it wrong. I think your putting your server side code into your Razor code (view i.e. **V** in MVC). [This is very, very wrong.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problem when I was learning upload. Problem is this line

```
if (fileContent.ContentType == "pdf")
```

It should be

```
if (fileContent.ContentType == "application/pdf")
```

It's MIME type, just in case if you do not know. Learn the functionality properly. Good luck :)

Comment: This worked. Thanks for now. I will have it learnt. Thank you